# Discord.js "DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction" error

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

There is a problem in the code I have given below. There is no problem with API requests. It sends requests to the API where the download is made, spotify api and url shortening api without any problem. There is a problem with Discord interaction, but I couldn't find the reason. Can you help me?

I thought removing the deferreplies would fix the problem but it didn't. There is a problem elsewhere.

Code Response:

```
PS C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main> node .
2 Eğik Çizgi Komutu, 0 Ön Ekli Komut Güncellendi
blxze#3330 Hazırlandı
{
  success: true,
  metadata: {
    id: '',
    artists: '',
    title: '',
    cover: '',
    album: '',
    releaseDate: '2013-05-13'
  },
  link: 'URL_WAS_HERE'
}
http://SHORT_URL/short/7t8Ens
http://SHORT_UR/short/pHRrLf
BQANj2tliXKN96luFq4NKy_T-nHANnPqMjdkz1ihz62_3TsRvt2ol45R5JXPY9jfN0xuVmcXO9zZraDYel3sriiz9p-bn9mYmJTneC9C75xuK3iubvM
USUM71703861
DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:687:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:786:23)
    at async _REST.request (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1218:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5)
    at async Object.execute (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\komutlar\downloader.js:117:13) {
  requestBody: { files: [], json: { type: 4, data: [Object] } },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1142396288911028244/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTE0MjM5NjI4ODkxMTAyODI0NDp0UE9yY3dJUjQyREdwZUZxcWxWTXNuZmNBZTlXRTZKdVZFRUNKdnJmNno3OGZVSmxGSHlCZ09ocUlmVzJkR0o3Z2ZOVmR0NURYSXBNUmdUaE5TYm5FaFk4MndMMEZJdzA0THJPMHpMTlZDZkM4NjFRRzhsRGhPcHplOHhkeFRkbw/callback'
}
Error [InteractionNotReplied]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.
    at ChatInputCommandInteraction.editReply (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:157:48)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\komutlar\downloader.js:120:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'InteractionNotReplied'
}
C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:687
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
            ^

DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:687:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:786:23)
    at async _REST.request (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1218:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5)
    at async Object.execute (C:\Users\skrpn\Desktop\Spotify-Tool-main\komutlar\downloader.js:129:5) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: 'An error occurred while processing your request.',
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
```

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');
const settings = require('../json/settings.json');
const distributors = require('../json/distributors.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    slash: true, 
    yetki: 'SendMessages', 
    botyetki: 'SendMessages', 
    cooldown: 10, 

    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('download')
        .setDescription('downloads song from spotify')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('songlink')
                .setDescription('song link')
                .setRequired(true)
        ),

    async execute(client, interaction) {
        const songlink = interaction.options.getString('songlink');
const songid = songlink.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];

if (!songid) {
    await interaction.reply('Invalid song link');
    return;
}

const headers = {
    'authority': 'DOWNLOADER_API',
    'origin': 'DOWNLOADER_API',
    'referer': 'DOWNLOADER_API',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
};

try {
    const response = await axios.get(`DOWNLOADER_API/download/${songid}`, {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'json',
        timeout: 15000
    });

    if (response.data.success === true && response.data.link) {
        try {
            const file = await axios.get(response.data.link, {
                headers: headers,
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                timeout: 15000
            });
            const cover = await axios.get(response.data.metadata.cover, {
                headers: headers,
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                timeout: 15000
            });
            console.log(response.data);

            const coverurl = await axios.get(`https://SECRET_URL/short/generate.php?url=${response.data.metadata.cover}`, {
                headers: headers,
                responseType: 'json',
                timeout: 15000
            }); 
            const songurl = await axios.get(`https://SECRET_URL/short/generate.php?url=${response.data.link}`, {
                headers: headers,
                responseType: 'json',
                timeout: 15000
            });
            
            const coverurlshort = coverurl.data.short_url;
            const songurlshort = songurl.data.short_url;

            console.log(coverurlshort);
            console.log(songurlshort);

            clientid = "CLIENT_ID"
            clientsecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"

            //spotify apiye istek gönder tokeni al
            const sporesponse = await axios.post(
                'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                new URLSearchParams({
                  'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                  'client_id': clientid,
                  'client_secret': clientsecret
                })
              );
            const token = sporesponse.data.access_token;
            console.log(token);
            const sporesponsee = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/11dFghVXANMlKmJXsNCbNl', {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                }
                });
                const isrc = sporesponsee.data.external_ids.isrc;
                const upc = sporesponsee.data.external_ids.upc;
                console.log(isrc);

            const resultembed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor(0x0099FF)
                .setTitle('Downloaded')
                .setURL('URL_HERE')
                .setDescription('Song downloaded successfully')
                .setThumbnail(coverurlshort) 
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Song', value: `${response.data.metadata.title}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Artist', value: `${response.data.metadata.artists}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Album', value: `${response.data.metadata.album}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Release Date', value: `${response.data.metadata.releaseDate}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'ISRC', value: `${isrc}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Link', value: `${songurlshort}`, inline: true },
                )
                .setTimestamp();
            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [resultembed] });
            } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.editReply({ content: 'An error occurred while processing your request.', ephemeral: true });
        }
        
    } else {
        await interaction.reply('Invalid song link');
        console.log(response.data);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.reply('An error occurred while processing your request.');
}

    }
};
```

[image: Discord Response]

Comment: I have hidden all private information. There is no problem with API requests.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming any of your other commands work whilst answering this:

Does this take more than 3 seconds? If so, your interaction must be deferred with `await interaction.deferReply()`, then responded to via `await interaction.editReply()`. Await is not strictly necessary, but makes more sense.